# A program that tells value of the items I return

Tags: python

This program does not work properly, it does not give me the value of the first bottle entered and does not sum the value correctly.
I have tried to understand what is the problem but cant really get it.

```
def main():
    CAN = 0
    GLASS_BOTTLE = 1
    PLASTIC_SMALL = 2
    PLASTIC_NORMAL = 3
    PLASTIC_BIG = 4
    NO_DEPOSIT_BOTTLE = 5
    CAN_DEPOSIT = 15  # cents
    GLASS_BOTTLE_DEPOSIT = 10  # cents
    PLASTIC_SMALL_DEPOSIT = 10  # cents
    PLASTIC_NORMAL_DEPOSIT = 20  # cents
    PLASTIC_BIG_DEPOSIT = 40  # cents

    print("Welcome to the bottle recycling.")
    print("Bottle types with the corresponding numbers:")
    print("Can: 0")
    print("Glass bottle: 1")
    print("Plastic bottle (0.33l): 2")
    print("Plastic bottle(0.5l): 3")
    print("Plastic bottle (1.5l): 4")
    print("No deposit bottle: 5")
    bottle = int(input("Enter the type of the first bottle. Stop with a negative number:\n"))
    c=0
    sum = 0
    while bottle >= 0:
        sum=sum + c
        bottle = int(input("Enter the type of the next bottle. Stop with a negative number:\n"))
        if 0:
            c = 15
        elif 1:
            c = 10
        elif 2:
            c = 10
        elif 3:
            c = 20
        elif 4:
            c = 40

    e = sum//100


    while sum > 100:
        sum-100

    print("You got", e, "\u20ac and",sum,"cents from the bottles")
main()
```

Comment: `if 0` should be `if bottle == 0`, and the same for all the other `if` statements.

Comment: You're also never doing anything with the first bottle.

Comment: Apply conditions with variable bottle

Comment: @Barmar I see that. How would I need to change the code to count also the first bottle? I have only done C before so python is kind of new to me

Comment: The logic is the same as in C. You could put the `if` blocks at the beginning of the `while` loop, instead of after it asks for the next bottle.

Comment: Why aren't you using any of the variables you set? Like `if bottle == CAN:`

Answer (score 0):

As already told, the problem is in the condition.
The first condition will always be False.

```
bool(0) == False
```

but the second one will be always True

```
bool(1) == True
```

the condition  must check the value of bottle, so

```
if bottle == 0:
```

and so on

Other than this, please don't use *sum* as a variable name, this is a [builtins function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)